# Follow/Unfollow with Ajax on Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I've been trying to implement Ajax for a while now and am unsuccessful in fully completing the process.

I can get it to post to the database no problem, but am having trouble with the JavaScript side of everything, more specifically showing the `unfollow` button to someone who has followed and the `follow` button to someone who has just unfollowed.

**Veiw**  -  *artists/show.html.erb*

```
<% if fan_signed_in? && current_fan.following_artist?(@artist) %>
  <%= button_to "unfollow", artist_relationship_path, method: :delete, remote: true, class: "exchange" %>
<% else %>
  <%= form_for(ArtistRelationship.new,  url: artist_relationships_path, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :artist_id, @artist.id %>
    <%= f.submit "follow", class: "exchange" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller** - *artists/relationships_controller.rb*

```
before_action :authenticate_fan!
respond_to :html, :js

def create
  @relationship = ArtistRelationship.new
  @relationship.fan_id = current_fan.id
  @relationship.artist_id = Artist.friendly.find(params[:artist_id]).id
  if @relationship.save
    redirect_to (:back)
  else
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end

def destroy
  current_fan.unfollow_artist(Artist.friendly.find(params[:id]))
  redirect_to (:back)
end
```

**View** - *artists/relationships.js.erb*

```
// I am lost here. I have no idea at all what goes in this file.
```

I also do not know if my controller is handling the request correctly. I just took that from a tutorial I've been following.

Any help would... help =]

**edit in response to beartech's answer**
I can click follow and it will successfully post to the database, however the view does not update. Upon refreshing the page, the follow button does show as unfollow and vice versa.

My logs say ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template artists/relationships/create) which makes sense as there is no create view for relationships as it's done on the artists/show.html.erb.

I'm almost positive something in the controller is not working properly with responding to the JavaScript.

Comment: Please don't use answer to post these comments. See how I used "edit" on your question to add the info above?

Comment: My edited answer should cause the create and delete actions to call the `follow_button.js.erb` which will update the `div`.

Comment: Ok. Can you map out your file structure a little, as you are nesting things beyond the assumed Rails layout. My code should work as it stands in the answer now. You may just have to adjust some file paths since you are nesting directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS file just needs to contain the code to change the button link from one state to the other. Since you have the `if/then` statement to determine which to show, you could put it in a div and have the JS update that div.

First you need to be able to respond to JS in your controller:

artists/relationships_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @relationship = ArtistRelationship.new
  @relationship.fan_id = current_fan.id
  @relationship.artist_id = Artist.friendly.find(params[:artist_id]).id
  if @relationship.save
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
      format.js {render :action => "follow_button" }
    end
  else
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end

def destroy
  current_fan.unfollow_artist(Artist.friendly.find(params[:id]))
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
    format.js {render :action => "follow_button" }
  end
end
```

Wrap your button code in a div:

artists/show.html.erb:

```
<div class='follow_button'>
<% if fan_signed_in? && current_fan.following_artist?(@artist) %>
  <%= button_to "unfollow", artist_relationship_path, method: :delete, remote: true, class: "exchange" %>
<% else %>
  <%= form_for(ArtistRelationship.new,  url: artist_relationships_path, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :artist_id, @artist.id %>
    <%= f.submit "follow", class: "exchange" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</div.
```

Now in your JS file:

artists/follow_button.js.erb:

```
$('#follow_button').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'follow_button') %>');
```

And the partial code:

artists/_follow_button.html.erb:

```
<% if fan_signed_in? && current_fan.following_artist?(@artist) %>
  <%= button_to "unfollow", artist_relationship_path, method: :delete, remote: true, class: "exchange" %>
<% else %>
  <%= form_for(ArtistRelationship.new,  url: artist_relationships_path, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :artist_id, @artist.id %>
    <%= f.submit "follow", class: "exchange" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You will probably need to adjust paths to suit your needs.

The lifecycle of AJAX is:

:remote call to controller -> respond to JS -> JS file gets executed.

Comment: Hmm, this does not work for me. Are we using a class or ID for the JavaScript? My view also goes `view => artists => artists => show.html.erb` does that matter? And lastly where am I saving the JavaScript file? `view/artists` or `view/artists/artists`?

Comment: It should go with your other view files. Are you nesting an directory named `artists` inside another directory named `artists`? And if so why? Also "does not work" means absolutely nothing when troubleshooting. What happens/doesn't happen? Post your web server log in the question.

Comment: OK, saw some problems with my code, which I was basing of some that I wrote for an app. Normally I use the same name for the controller action, the JS file and the partial.

Comment: The big things are rename the JS file as shown and add the render action to the JS response in the controller so it knows what file to call.

Comment: You may need to nest both the `_follow_button.html.erb` and `follow_button.js.erb` in a folder called `relationships` in your `views` folder because the controller is going to look for the files in `views/relationships/..` It really doesn't matter if they are in another folder like that because that is where Rails is going to look for them. You could probably specify the path easily, I just haven't done it.

Comment: Yup, you were right with the whole nesting the partial and JS file in the relationships folder. The Ajax part does work, but the partial will not display because of a problem finding the ID of the `current_fan` in the Relatonships model. It has to do with the `following_artist?` method. That goes way beyond this I'm guessing. Thank you for your help!

Comment: When the .erb files are rendered your current instance variables should still be accessible. I have used instance variables in my partials for dynamic content.

Comment: Yeah, I honestly can't see it fails to read the instance variables. If I replace the follow button code on the page with the `follow_button` partial it displays, so it isn't the code in the partial failing. For some reason, it doesn't seem to be reading the `ActiveRecord` properly once the Ajax is committed.

Comment: So after some playing around I figured out that it has to do with this line in the `ArtistRelationship.new form`: `<%= hidden_field_tag :artist_id, @artist.id %>`. It seems as if it's looking for `@artist` in the `relationships_controller.rb` `create` method and not the `artists_controller.rb` `show` method like it does otherwise.

Comment: That's because it's the `relationships_controller` that is handling that instance variable. You can set that variable again in the `relationships_controller.rb :create` method or even in the partial, but this is why I would have just made the toggling of the relationships a method in the `artists_controller.rb`.